# How to write help() documentation to a file Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was looking at the help() documentation of a module but soon realized it was very tedius to read the documentation in the small output box. So therefore I tried pasting the help() documentation to another file for more clearer reading.

```
myfile = open("file.txt","w") 
myfile.write(str(help(random)))
myfile.close()
```

Instead of the documentation being written, it instead pasted in `None`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you don't read the files that are available online, i.e. the documentation?

Comment: [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) does not return anything.

Comment: The [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) documentation is available online.

Comment: I guess that works too; was interested if there was a way to paste it on a document.

Comment: Are you looking for [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)!. Run it from the console:

```
$ pydoc [modulename] > file.txt
```

and it will basically write the output of the `help()` command to `file.txt`

Comment: did not know that one! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

i'm not suggesting you should read the python documentation this way - but here is what you could do: you could redirect `stdout` and call `help`:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import random

with open('random_help.txt', 'w') as file:
    with redirect_stdout(file):
        help(random)
```

or, even simpler (as suggested by Jon Clements):

```
from pydoc import doc
import random

with open('random_help.txt', 'w') as file:
    doc(random, output=file)
```

Comment: You can avoid redirecting standard out... Use `pydoc.doc(random, output=file)` to explicitly write the output to a stream.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the suggestion! added it to the answer.